# Mainstream physics closed as non-mainstream

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

[This (admittedly naive) question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/359310/how-do-we-know-tachyons-dont-exist-second-try) (asking whether the existence of tachyons would have observable consequences) seems to me to be clearly about mainstream physics, though it was closed as non-mainstream.

If the answer is that the existence of tachyons would have observable consequences that contradict mainstream physics, that answer is mainstream physics.

Mainstream textbooks often say things like "Perpetual motion machines are impossible because they would have such-and-such observable consequences which contradict other things we know about".  Why can't a mainstream Q&A treat tachyons the same way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/359310/revisions) (v2) that was closed as non-mainstream read:

> Title: How would a tachyonic antitelephone work?
>
> [...]
>
> So here's my question. Let's say that in the year 2067, a highly advanced alien race decides to send a message back in time 50 years to Earth in 2017. How could they send such a signal so that it could be detected by 2017 technology? I understand this isn't possible under mainstream physics, but let's assume mainstream physics is wrong. Hypothetically, how could it happen?

The question was later edited by OP, and is currently (Sept 27, 2017) in the review queue.

Comment: Thanks for this.   I ought to have looked at the edit history before posting.